# System.Runtime.Remoting.RemotingException: Requested Service not found after Hosting Rest web service implementing IhttpHandler

Tags: c#

**Error Message**

> After Hosting Rest web service implementing IhttpHandler, i get System.Runtime.Remoting.RemotingException: Requested Service not found,

below is the code

```
public class MyService:IHttpHandler
{

    #region Handler
    bool IHttpHandler.IsReusable
    {
        get { throw new NotImplementedException(); }
    }

    void IHttpHandler.ProcessRequest(HttpContext context)
    {

        HttpResponse objResponse = context.Response;
        objResponse.Write("<html><body><h1>Hell world");
        objResponse.Write("</body></html>");


    }
}
```

Url: http://localhost/MyService/bill.soap

Answer (score 0):

I solved it by changing the preCondition attribute on handler in web.config.
the attribute should match with application poll used by application.

```
<handlers>
            <add name="test" path="bill.soap" verb="*" modules="IsapiModule" scriptProcessor="C:\Windows\Microsoft.NET\Framework\v2.0.50727\aspnet_isapi.dll" resourceType="Unspecified" requireAccess="Script" preCondition="classicMode,runtimeVersionv4.0,bitness32" />
        </handlers>
```

More details : http://helpcentral.componentone.com/netHelp/AR9/ConfigureHTTPHandlersinIIS7x.html